# Can I install Windows 8.1 as Bootcamp partition from OSX Mountain Lion using a USB stick?

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, osx-mountain-lion, boot-camp

I have the following:

1. Bootable USB stick with Windows 8.1 - 64 bit
2. MacBook Pro with Mountain Lion 10.8.5
3. The Bootcamp partition currently has Windows 7 installed.

I want to know whether I can install Windows 8.1 from a USB stick into a Bootcamp partition. Apple's article on the topic refers to Bootcamp 5.1, but my OSX install has Bootcamp 5.0 - I am assuming 5.1 comes with the Mavericks version.

Thus my question.  So can I?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly. Yes, you can.
 Apple has compatibility information here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5634

If you where wondering how (which seems like a better question, but anyways), you can follow one of these tutorials: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4211110